# use Python to pass a list of objects as pool map arguments

Tags: python, object, multiprocessing, pool

I am experiencing with Python Multiprocessing and got stuck with passing a list of object as pool.map arguments. The following codes print [None, None] instead of actual names. Can anybody shed some light on it?

```js
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Item:
  def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
    self.firstname = firstname
    self.lastname = lastname

def get_items():
  items = []
  names = ['Joe Smith', 'Rick Harvard']

  for name in names:
      item = Item(name.split(' ')[0], name.split(' ')[1])
      items.append(item)

  return items

def f(name):
    print(name.firstname, name.lastname)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
  p = Pool(16)
  print(p.map(f, get_items()))
  p.close()
  p.join()
```

Comment: ***"print [None, None] "***: This is correct, you call `def f(...` two times and `def f(...` return two times `None`.

Comment: but why it didn't print 'Joe,Smith' and 'Rick,Harvard'?

Comment: Did you say: `print(name....` in `def f(...` did not show up?

Answer (score 1):

The print method returns None and you call it twice

change your f function to

```
def f(name):
    return name.firstname, name.lastname
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked.